# Revoke delete permission for particular user in linux

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, winscp, acl

I have to revoke delete permission for particular user in Linux. I have tried ACL it worked but user is able to delete file winscp. My requirement is that user is not able to delete file from PUtty and winscp.

T